# Flyway 4.0.3 won't connect to MySQL server 8.0.17

Tags: mysql, flyway

Recently I update my local MySQL from 5.7 to 8.0.17 to fix a known bug (don't keep ID auto-increment sequence after restart) and after it Flyway (4.0.3) can't connect to the Database.

**1**- I've checked the database user credentials, are the same applied to the previous version (MySQL 5.7). SSL on the connection is disabled 
**2**- Checked the compatibility between flyway 4.0.3 and MySQL 8.0.17 and it's compatible according to flyway documentation

Reading forums and discussions about this issue I'm almost convinced that is as MySQL configuration (file my.ini) issue but, I didn't found any tip or fix to apply.

> *************** Error ********************
>   Mon Aug 12 09:08:28 EDT 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity
>   verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+
>   and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default
>   if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing
>   applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set
>   to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting
>   useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server
>   certificate verification. ERROR: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from
>   DataSource (jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name) for user
>   'xyz_user': Could not create connection to database server.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this in my Flask app by finding my flyway url string and appending `useSSL=false` to it.

```
FLYWAY_URL=jdbc:mysql://{}:3306/{}?useSSL=false
```